# How to debug Unknown word error while building my Next.js site?

Tags: next.js

I'm running `npm run build` on my website and I get this error:

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: /Activity/SiteNext/static/css/4a5b71b9df803fb8.css:1085:26: Unknown word
    at makeWebpackError (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:308185)
    at /next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:105236
    at eval (eval at create (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28771), <anonymous>:34:1)
-- inner error --
CssSyntaxError: /Activity/SiteNext/static/css/4a5b71b9df803fb8.css:1085:26: Unknown word
    at Input.error (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:148:16)
    at ScssParser.unknownWord (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:540:22)
    at ScssParser.other (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:164:12)
    at ScssParser.parse (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:72:16)
    at scssParse (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:322)
    at new LazyResult (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
    at Processor.process (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:28:14)
    at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (/next/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:42:12)
    at /next/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:74:55
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/next/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
CssSyntaxError: /Activity/SiteNext/static/css/4a5b71b9df803fb8.css:1085:26: Unknown word
    at Input.error (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:148:16)
    at ScssParser.unknownWord (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:540:22)
    at ScssParser.other (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:164:12)
    at ScssParser.parse (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:72:16)
    at scssParse (/next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:322)
    at new LazyResult (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
    at Processor.process (/next/node_modules/next/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:28:14)
    at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (/next/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:42:12)
    at /next/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:74:55
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/next/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
```

As you can see, it does not tell me anything about my code. It just says that something does not work while minifying the style.

If I run `npm run dev` everything works perfectly and there is no error. But I'm stuck at building my site.

The codebase is not small, thus I can't manually check everything in styles. I need to find out a way to do it systematically.

I'm using Tailwind CSS and SASS.

I have searched and found some answers. But the are all related to very specific problems that do not solve mine.

Also [CssSyntaxError - unknown word in Tailwind and Next.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73923945/csssyntaxerror-unknown-word-in-tailwind-and-next-js-project) does not have answers.

Comment: This probably is some syntax error in the code, can you provide your code or specify more?